# Grouping a dictionary NSFetchRequest by object ID

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

I need to return a list of objects along with a count of its related objects. It doesn't seem to be possible to do this in a single dictionary fetch request as I am unable to group the fetch results by objectID.

```
let objectIDExpression = NSExpressionDescription()
objectIDExpression.name = "objectID"
objectIDExpression.expression = NSExpression.expressionForEvaluatedObject()
objectIDExpression.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.ObjectIDAttributeType

let countExpression = NSExpressionDescription()
countExpression.name = "count"
countExpression.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "count:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "entries")])
countExpression.expressionResultType = .Integer32AttributeType

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tag")
fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [objectIDExpression, countExpression]
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = [objectIDExpression]

var error: NSError?
if let results = self.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) {
    println(results)
}
```

When this request executes it errors with:

```
'Invalid keypath expression ((<NSExpressionDescription: 0x7f843bf2d470>), name objectID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity (null), renamingIdentifier objectID, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}) passed to setPropertiesToFetch:'
```

I also tested just passing the `"objectID"` expression name, but that also fails.

Is there therefore no way to group by object ID?

Comment: Looks like the error is in `[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "Entries")]`, presumably referring to a to-many relationship, name cannot be capitalized according to Core Data rules.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the sample code. I've also elaborated on the error message. To be clear, the error only occurs if I set the `propertiesToGroupBy` property. Without it, the fetch works but there is no grouping by each "tag" object.

Comment: Is the relatnioship one-many, or many-many?  Ie can an Entry have multiple Tags?

Comment: @pbasdf It's a many-many relationship between tags and entries.

Comment: Pity... if it were one-many, you could just fetch `Entries` and group by `Tag`.  I guess you could explicitly model the many-many relationship with an intermediate entity, and use that entity in the fetch.  But that's a messy solution which will require wholesale changes to the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the required count *without using `propertiesToGroupBy`*.  CoreData seems to infer the correct scope for the count and uses a sub-SELECT instead (strangely, only if the fetch includes an attribute as well as the objectID and count, see below).  For example, I have `Tag` many-many with `Items`:

[image: Data Model]

**First attempt**

I can fetch `tagName` and the count of items as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tag"];
NSExpressionDescription *countED = [NSExpressionDescription new];
countED.expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"count:(items)"];
countED.name = @"countOfItems";
countED.expressionResultType = NSInteger64AttributeType;
fetch.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetch.propertiesToFetch = @[@"tagName", countED];
NSArray *results = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
NSLog(@"results is %@", results);
```

which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.ZTAGNAME, (SELECT COUNT(t1.Z_3ITEMS) FROM Z_3TAGS t1 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_8TAGS) ) FROM ZTAG t0
```

**Second attempt**

Sadly, it seems CoreData gets confused if I try to select the objectID instead of the `tagName`:

```
NSExpressionDescription *selfED = [NSExpressionDescription new];
selfED.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
selfED.name = @"self";
selfED.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;
fetch.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetch.propertiesToFetch = @[selfED, countED];
```

generates this SQL:

```
SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, COUNT( t1.Z_3ITEMS) FROM ZTAG t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN Z_3TAGS t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_8TAGS
```

which counts all the rows from the outer join (and suggests that you need to group by the objectID, though we know that won't work).

**Final attempt**

However, include `tagName` *and* objectID, and all is well again:

```
fetch.propertiesToFetch = @[selfED, @"tagName", countED];
```

gives:

```
SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZTAGNAME, (SELECT COUNT(t1.Z_3ITEMS) FROM Z_3TAGS t1 WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_8TAGS) ) FROM ZTAG t0
```

which seems to do the trick.  (Sorry for reverting to Objective-C, and for using different entity/attribute names, but I'm sure you get the picture).

**Aside**

One other curiosity I discovered is that the second attempt above can also be made to work by counting an attribute of the relationship, rather than the relationship itself:

```
countED.expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"count:(items.itemName)"];
fetch.propertiesToFetch = @[selfED, countED];
```

gives:

```
SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, (SELECT COUNT(t2.ZITEMNAME) FROM Z_3TAGS t1 JOIN ZITEMS t2 ON t1.Z_3ITEMS = t2.Z_PK WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_8TAGS) ) FROM ZTAG t0
```

which will (I think) give the correct counts provided `itemName` is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps easier to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. You can set the `sectionNameKeyPath` to group and use the resulting `NSIndexPath`s to construct your dictionary.

That being said, I do not think that it makes any sense to group by objectID because every object ID is by definition unique. So there will be one instance in each group. This is likely why setting `propertiesToGroupBy` fails.

So, short answer: no.

E.g.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Tag")
var output = [(NSManagedObjectID, Int)]()
do {
   let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Tag]
   for tag in results { 
       output.append((tag.objectID, tag.entries.count))
   }
} catch {}
// output contains tuples with objectID and count
```

If `entries`is optional, use `tag.entries?.count ?? 0`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help in my situation. I basically need an efficient way to end up with a mapping of `Tag` objects to an integer count of how many related `Entry` objects it has. I don't want to simply fetch all my tag objects and count the size of the relationship set as I don't want to fault all the related objects into the context, as there could be hundreds per tag. And I believe (I may be wrong though) that counting the size of the set would fault related objects. I.e. `count(tag.entries)`

Comment: See my amended answer. I think there is some confusion about the object ID.

Comment: Every objectID is unique so that is why I want to group by it. I want an array of dictionaries, each with 2 keys, the objectID, and the count of how many entries it is related to

Comment: I think it would be very efficient with the FRC. I don't see how the entries would be de-faulted. Just loop through `fetchedObjects` and get `entries.count`. I have done similar things with 100.000s of records on old hardware such as the first iPad without any problems. A fetch request for all `Tag`s would perform in a similar way.

Comment: It seems that `entries.count` incurs a DB hit in order to create the related object faults. If you set `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` then it will batch get the relationship data, so each call to `entries.count` will no longer hit the DB (perfect if there's a lot of objects to iterate). I think a regular fetch (with prefetch) and counting relationship sets is going to be the best way around this until a way to group dictionary fetches by object is available.

Answer (score 0):

I played with this for a bit, sure there had to be some way to tell core-data to group by the primary key.

I couldn't figure it out, though I believe it to be possible.

The best I could do was add another unique attribute "uuid" (which I use for all of my entities anyway, for various reasons).  You can do this easily enough with `NSUUID`, or you can take the permanent object ID URI representation and turn it into a string.

Anyway, I think this gives you what you want, but does so by requiring a separate unique attribute.

```
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"uuid"];
```

I tried a bunch of alternatives as the group-by property but `expressionForEvaluatedObject` always barfs, and other attempts fell flat.

I'm sure you know this already.  Just in case, though it's at least a workaround, even if you don't use it for anything else, until someone comes around who has actually done this before.

FWIW, here is the SQL...

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, COUNT( t1.Z_1ENTRIES), t0.ZUUID
    FROM ZTAG t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN Z_1TAGS t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_2TAGS
    GROUP BY  t0.ZUUID
```

Surely, there has to be a way to tell it to substitute `t0.Z_PK` in the group-by clause.  I would image that should be an easy special case for `expressionForEvaluatedObject` or "objectID" or "self" or "self.objectID"

Good luck, and please report back if you solve it.  I'd be very interested.

Comment: Yes it's very strange isn't it, there must be a way! In the mean time I'm using another unique field as you said, but I'll make sure to report back if I do find any way around it!

Comment: @JodyHagins This seems to be possible without using `propertiesToGroupBy` - see my separate answer.